# Stieltjes measure function to Lebesgue Measure?

Tags: measure-theory

I have started reading Rick Durrett's "Probability: Theory and Examples" Edition 4.1.

There is a section quite at the beginning that I do not understand. it starts OK but then at the last line "When
F
(
x
) =
x
the resulting measure is called
Lebesgue measure"

Does this imply that when the domain and co-domain has the same value the Stieltjes measure function becomes a Lebesgue Measure? What i have understood so far about Lebesgue Measure doesn't include this definition.

Quote:

"Associated with each Stieltjes measure function
F
there is a unique
measure μ on ( $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathcal{R}$)

with
μ
((
a,b
]) =
F
(
b
)
−
F
(
a
)

When
F
(
x
) =
x
the resulting measure is called
Lebesgue measure."

Comment: When two measures on the same sigma-algebra give the same numerical values to every sets in that sigma-algebra, they're simply the same measure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Durrett's notation, a Stieltjes measure function is a function $F : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that is nondecreasing and right-continuous, whereas $\mu : \mathcal{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ assigns a measure to every Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$.  Every Stieltjes function $F$ defines a $\mu$.  $F$ doesn't need to be the identity function, but if it is, then the $\mu$ of Theorem 1.1.2 is called Lebesgue measure.